# Prolog simple recursion

Tags: prolog

This is a really simple quesiton but I don't get it.

```
insert(X, L, [X|L]).
insert(X, [H|T], [H|T2]) :-
    insert(X, T, T2).
```

We run it with `insert(1, [2,3], L).`

When it's called the 1st insert produces (1, [2,3], [1|2,3]) > L = [1,2,3], then it looks at the second insert(1, [2|3], [2|T2]) // T2 is a variable im guessing.. and it calls insert(1, [3], T2) which calls the 1st insert again with insert(1, [3], [1|3]) > L = [1,3],

which is not true, because it actually returns L = [2,1,3]. What am I missing about recursions?

Comment: Syntax correction `[1|[2,3]]` not `[1|2,3]` and `[2|[3]]` not `[2|3]`.

Comment: You neglected to unravel the full recursion in your second example. The call to `insert(1, [2|[3]], L)` matches the second clause with `insert(1, [2|[3]], [2|T2])` which calls `insert(1, [3], T2)`. That call yields `T2 = [1,3]` as you show, but that leads to the final result `[2|[1,3]]` or simply `L = [2,1,3]`.

Comment: Aha ok, so after this example returns, how does it get the 3rd and last result? I'm guessing that when you call the second example it calls the first insert and returns and also calls the second insert(1, [3|[]], [3|T2]) which calls insert(1, [], T2) and T2 = [1] and that would get me [3,1], seems like I don't clearly get it.

Comment: Remember the recursive call also has a choice of matching either the first predicate clause or the second.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`insert` generates three values

```
insert(X, L, [X|L]).            %fact(1)
insert(X, [H|T], [H|T2]) :-     %fact(2)
    insert(X, T, T2).

?- insert(1,[2,3],L).
L = [1, 2, 3] ;
L = [2, 1, 3] ;
L = [2, 3, 1].
```

Lets see how it works:

`insert(1,[2,3],L)` for `fact(1)` generates `L=[1,2,3]`

`insert(1,[2,3],L)` for `fact(2)`:

```
insert(1,[2|[3]],[2|T2]) :-
    insert(1,[3],T2) :-             %check fact(1)
        insert(1,[3],[1|[3])        %T2 = [1,3]
```

so `L=[2|T2]=[2,1,3].`

Moreover:

`insert(1,[2,3],L)` for `fact(2)` generates another value,

```
insert(1,[2|[3]],[2|T2]) :-
    insert(1,[3],T2) :-             %check fact(2)
        insert(1,[3|[]],[3|T3]) :-  %check fact(2) T2=[3,1]
            insert(1,[],[1])        %check fact(1) T3=[1]
```

so `L=[2|T2]=[2,3,1]`

Comment: Ok I somehow get it, although coming up with the solution seems harder than understanding it. Btw... since this recursion ends, does it end because [H|T] tries to split [] into 2 parts but it can't?

Comment: You may say that, but I think when learning prolog you should think and talk in terms of prolog.

In my opinion you should say that prolog **backtracking** possible solutions for your query (not just doing recursion).

It starts backtracking after finding `L=[1,2,3]` (after `fact(1)`)

While backtracking, the last query `insert(1,[],T2)` is satisfied (returned true), so no more backtracking needed.

(btw remember to pick an answer by pressing the V icon near the votes so it turn green)